# Python Numpy arrays, Vlookup like function

Tags: python, numpy, vlookup

I would like to ask for your help. The problem in steps.
1. Import two excel files into Python Data frames - so far no problem
2. Transferring the data frames into numpy arrays.
3. Create a VLOOKUP function in python, with the arrays. Both arrays have a key in the first column, which is unique and can be used for matching. The two tables include data, which is correct in one table but not in the other one. I would like to overwrite values in the table where values are wrong from the table where values are correct (I know, which table is has the right values...)

Is there a more numpy way to do it;

## So far the code I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()

s = pd.read_excel("C:\a.xlsx")

r = pd.read_excel("C:\b.xlsx")

z=s.values

t = r.values
```

## Here matching the two arrays, and overwriting the value

```
for i in z:

    for j in t:

        if z[i, 0] == t[j, 0]:

            t[i, 41] = z[j, 5]
```

Comment: @ what are the columns ? what is the key column name which table has correct and which has wrong ? which column you want to copy ? Add all the details in the question so that others can understand the problem.

Comment: Array z has 27 columns (originally excel a). Array t has 51 columns (originally excel b). I want to copy the value of the column 5 of the z table to the column 41 of the t table. Where there is a match in the key. I have done this in VBA (two loops) and SQL (INNER JOIN, UPDATE) as well.  And the whole thing now I try to replicate in python, but this is the part where I am struggling. Why I want to replicate in python is performance issue, there are almost 1 million lines in each table. And later on data analysis could be much faster in python as well.....

Answer (score 0):

If same length, use pd.merge, it acts like vlookup:

```
newdf = s.merge(r, on ='same_key')
```

newdf will have all the columns from both data frames. You can now access the individual columns you need to update:

```
newdf['wrongcolumn'] = newdf['rightcolumn']
```